# How can I give a radio button a value and determine the selected radio button without using a GroupBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, radio-button, controls

I have a form with few radio buttons that suppose to represent different integer values.

1) Is there a **built-in** way to put a value "behind" a radio button? 
an example:

```
RadioButton rad = new RadioButton();
rad.Value = 5; // This is what im trying to achieve.
```

2) I have few RadioButtons that are logically related to each other and i want to know which one was selected (**without** putting them inside a GroupBox control) and get the selected value for that RadioButton.
note: I would like to "Iterate" these 3 controls and get the selected one instead of doing 3 IF statements.
an example:

```
RadioButton radColor1 = new RadioButton();
RadioButton radColor2 = new RadioButton();
RadioButton radColor3 = new RadioButton();

// ...

RadioButton radSelected = ?? // Get selected Radio Button from the 3 above.
//here i can get to radSelected.Value
```

Comment: Your question contains two different topics. Please post two seperate questions the next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to assign an arbitrary value to the control, use its `Tag` property:

```
radColor1.Tag = 5;
```

But why can't you simply use the `Checked` property?

```
if (radColor1.Checked)
    //do something
if (radColor2.Checked)
    //do something else
//...however many more you need to check
```

EDIT:  iteration...

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is RadioButton)
    {
        if (((RadioButton)c).Checked)
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to "Iterate" these 3 controls and get the selected one instead of doing 3 IF statements.

Comment: Regarding the (1)'s solution: the Tag property definitely helps, i wasn't sure about if should i use it or not. (2): The only problem is that u actually iterating the entire radio buttons on the form and i want to "iterate" certain number of them without putting them inside a groupbox or something like that. maybe i should use a panel for them?

Comment: You'll need some way to distinguish them.  A containing control of some kind works.  Naming them a certain way works.  Flagging each using `Tag` works.  But if it's 3/10 radio buttons, you need to spot them somehow.

Answer (score 2):

put these radio btns in a `stackPanel` and iterate to check `If Checked` & than use `tag` property to store the values of each `radio button`

```
foreach(var child in stack.Children)
{
    if((child as RadioButton).Checked == true)
    var value = (child as RadioButton).tag;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RadioButton radSelected = (from RadioButton rb in this.Controls
                          where rb.Checked 
                          select rb).SingleOrDefault();
```